# How to click only on the text of a header and not the empty whitespace to the right?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I am trying to make a link on a header be clickable on the **text** of the header only. Problem is, in my case, the link is still clickable, even when there is no text(it still clicks on empty blue space to the right).
Example:

[image: header image]

as you can see, the whole blue is clickable, but I just want the click to end after the "Hello World Link" word.

Is there a way to allow to click only on the text "Hello World Link" and not the rest of blue empty space to the right?

My code:

```
<a href="blah blaha ">
   <div class="headerText">
       <h2>@title</h2>
   </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
  .headerText{
       h2:hover {
         background-color: yellow;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `display: inline-block;` on your `.headerText` DIV

```css
.headerText {
  display: inline-block;
}
.headerText h2:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="blah blaha ">
   <div class="headerText">
       <h2>@title</h2>
   </div>
</a>
```

SCSS:

```
.headerText{
  display: inline-block;

  h2:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, this helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For applying link to text only, move the `a` element just above the text element(here `h2`).
Try this:

```
<div class="headerText">
  <a href="blah blaha ">
    <h2>@title</h2>
  </a>
</div>
```

Also check the style of `h2`. If it has a fixed width wider than the text, it may cause again this problem. Better to provide an HTML,CSS snippet in the question.

Comment: I proved the CSS above. Basically, I am trying to highlight the header text on hover with yellow color.  With this is current CSS, it is highlighting the full width in yellow. How can I set the width to just fit the length of the text?

Comment: Hard to understand the issue from the provided CSS. Could you please provide an HTML/CSS snippet for reproducing the exact scenario? It's there in the stack-overflow editor options.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know whitch are the defined styles of yours components, but on some cases you can use the css empty pseudo class, and set the pointer-events property as none. This approach just work in the case that the element doesn't have any children and also the element content is empty.

```
a:empty {
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had not understood the problem, I've just seen the image.